# Dilemma: a huge sprite & inline style tags VS. no inline style tags and many images

Tags: image, css-sprites, web-standards, inline-styles

I have an application in which the user will 'upload' a lot of (small-size, from **5 to 20kb** each) images to the HTML page, and will drag and drop them to different locations on the page (with jQuery). I have the choice of making them input images either as separate files, or as a sprite. I'm wondering what is the better choice with regards to both performance and webstandards, with the file size in consideration and this statement: **user experience doesn't matter in this case** (having to input files one by one)

Either... or

1. Many (more than 200) inline style tags with `background-position: abpx abpx;` and 1 sprite.
   **--> Bad for webstandards, good for pagespeed**
2. Many images (more than 200)
   **--> Good for webstandards, bad for pagespeed**

Comment: Are these decorative images? Or are the images relevant to the content?

Comment: @unor late comment, but they are important for the page